# Taking JSON data, grouping by a property, and aggregating using multiple aggregation functions

Tags: javascript, json, aggregate

Here is a sample of JSON data of fruit weights and prices:

```
let fruitData = [{"fruit":"apple","weight":12,"price":1.80},
                 {"fruit":"apple","weight":15,"price":2.00},
                 {"fruit":"apple","weight":10,"price":1.60},
                 {"fruit":"banana","weight":22,"price":3.00},
                 {"fruit":"banana","weight":24,"price":3.20}]
```

If I want to group by the "fruit" property and return mean "weight" and "price" values for each fruit, what do I do to achieve this? The end result would be something like:

```
aggFruitData = [{"fruit":"apple","weight":12.3333,"price":1.8},
                {"fruit":"banana","weight":23,"price":3.1}]
```

The big hope is that the data can still be in an easy to manipulate form like JSON following the transformation. I know that SQL provides a groupby method, but I'm wondering if that is more efficient or if using native JS is more effective. Ideally, this could be something that could be scaled up, such as including another property to group by (maybe like month sold/month price was recorded). I'm open to using either vanilla JS methods or a library/framework meant to parse in this way— I just want efficiency with the project's execution

Comment: Please be aware that you have no JSON in the question. You are referring to js objects and arrays.

Comment: Oh, I see that there's a difference between the two classes of objects. What's the biggest difference between the two? I'm currently looking at differences but they don't look especially different even when labeled. (At least in relation to the type of data I gave)

Comment: Are you responding to my comment? If so, I only meant that neither `fruitData` nor `aggFruitData` are JSON.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking what gives it away/why it isn't JSON

Comment: Ok cool. JSON is always a string. `'true'` is valid JSON. JSON always needs parsing to be used as a JS object. `JSON.parse('{ "hello": "world" }')`

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you for clarifying, that makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vanilla js:

```
let fruitData = [{
    "fruit": "apple",
    "weight": 12,
    "price": 1.80
  },
  {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "weight": 15,
    "price": 2.00
  },
  {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "weight": 10,
    "price": 1.60
  },
  {
    "fruit": "banana",
    "weight": 22,
    "price": 3.00
  },
  {
    "fruit": "banana",
    "weight": 24,
    "price": 3.20
  }
];
const aggregated = Object.values(fruitData.reduce((current, item) => {
  if (!current[item.fruit]) {
    current[item.fruit] = {
      ...item,
      count: 1
    };
  } else {
    const i = current[item.fruit];
    i.weight = (i.weight * i.count + item.weight) / (i.count + 1);
    i.price = (i.price * i.count + item.price) / (i.count + 1);
    i.count++;
  }
  return current;
}, {})).map(({
  fruit,
  weight,
  price
}) => ({
  fruit,
  weight,
  price
}));
console.log(aggregated);
// [ { fruit: 'apple', weight: 12.333333333333334, price: 1.8 },
// { fruit: 'banana', weight: 23, price: 3.1 } ]
```

You could also use the lodash library (_.groupBy etc) functions for this. Note that the last `.map` is to strip out the count field only, but you may actually find it useful to have that!

Comment: This works beautifully! I'm going to unpack this to make sure I understand, but I'm happy to say it works.